# PHP - Get Chinese string between two tags

Tags: php, substr

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = mb_strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += mb_strlen($start);
    $len = mb_strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return mb_substr($string, $ini, $len, mb_detect_encoding($string));
}

$string = '<div>財物類</div>';

$parsed = get_string_between($string, '<div>', '</div>');

echo $parsed;
```

Here is the result I'm getting: è²¡ç‰©é¡ž

The result I obviously want is: 財物類

Comment: This *is* the string you want, just not interpreted with the correct encoding. Figure out what the thing you're trying to view this on expects and convert to that encoding.

Comment: I'm currently outputting it on Chrome: http://idolmemory.com/search.php

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML like this, use a proper parser like [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in my env, you simply need to set the file encoding to UTF-8 using your text editor.
Or if it is a Browser problem, to be sure, add

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

before

```
echo $parsed;
```

Which would force the browser to interpret the server response encoding as UTF-8, it is always advised to send this header actually if you are coding in UTF-8 (your response e.g. HTML encoding is UTF-8).

Comment: Assuming that the source code is encoded with UTF-8, of course.

Comment: Hi, no problem, you may also use `Content-Type: text/plain` instead of `Content-Type: text/html` if you are sending only text and no HTML.